# AppleScript with multiple finder inputs

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, osx-yosemite, automator

**THE WHAT AND WHY**
From inside Finder I want to be able to make hidden any files/folders, regardless if sudo is required or not, by a simple right click.

**STEPS TAKEN ALREADY:**
After a bunch of experimenting I settled on an Automator service running an AppleScript

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set filehide1 to {}
  repeat with filehide2 in input
  set end of filehide1 to POSIX path of filehide2
  end repeat
  do shell script "chflags hidden " & quote & filehide1 & quote with administrator privileges
end run
```

**ISSUE:**
So the script works peachy BUT in it's present form only when one item at a time is selected. How do I tweak Automator / AppleScript to work regardless if its 1 file or 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an AppleScript list to the shell. You have to flatten the list and separate the file paths by space characters. This can be done with `text item delimiters`.

The script escapes each file path in the repeat loop so the quotes are not needed in the `do shell script` line.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set filehide1 to {}
    repeat with filehide2 in input
        set end of filehide1 to quoted form of POSIX path of filehide2
    end repeat
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, space}
    set fileList to filehide1 as text
    set text item delimiters to TID
    do shell script "chflags hidden " & fileList with administrator privileges
end run
```

Comment: AWESOME thanks! I should have asked for help a lot sooner instead of screaming at Google for failing me.  Cheers and Happy New Years!